# Printing the content of each subarray on individual lines

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array code, like :

```
$responeArray = array();
$_counter = 0;
foreach ($xmlResp->readCalls->classify as $readCalls) {
    $ClassificationClass = array();
    foreach ($readCalls->classification->{'class'} as $classes) {
        $ClassificationClass[] = implode(" ", array('p' => (string)$classes['p']));
    }
    $responeArray[] = $ClassificationClass;
    $_counter++;
}
return $responeArray;
```

that will give result like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.999999
            [1] => 5.65423e-007
            [2] => 2.3301e-008
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.333333
            [1] => 0.333333
            [2] => 0.333333
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.19172e-007
            [1] => 0.999993
            [2] => 6.75659e-006
        )
)
```

**my purpose to get result like**

```
0.999999 5.65423e-007 2.3301e-008
...
1.19172e-007 0.999993 6.75659e-006
```

I tried using this

```
$responeArray = array();
$_counter = 0;
foreach ($xmlResp->readCalls->classify as $readCalls) {
    $ClassificationClass = array();
    foreach ($readCalls->classification->{'class'} as $classes) {
        $ClassificationClass[] = implode(" ", array('p' => (string)$classes['p']));
    }
    $responeArray[] = $ClassificationClass;
    $nilaineg = $ClassificationClass[0];
    $nilainet = $ClassificationClass[1];
    $nilaipos = $ClassificationClass[2];
    $_counter++;
}
return $nilaineg . ' ' . $nilainet . ' ' . $nilaipos;
```

but code above just outputs:

```
1.19172e-007 0.999993 6.75659e-006
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
    $array = array
(
    array(
        0.999999,
        5.65423e-007,
        2.3301e-008
    ),

    array
    (
        0.333333,
        0.333333,
        0.333333
    ),

    array
    (
        1.19172e-007,
        0.999993,
        6.75659e-006
    )
);

foreach($array as $item)
    print_r(implode(" ", $item)."\n");
```

Comment: Hi Larry, i think you miss my question.. can you? thanks Larry

Comment: I think you would output the string value to client-side using special format, so I make this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're only taking one variable from the entire loop. As you're overwriting the last set of rows each time. Change your code remove the `return` and place an `echo` from inside the loop, like below:

```
$responeArray = array();
$_counter = 0;
foreach ($xmlResp->readCalls->classify as $readCalls) {
    $ClassificationClass = array();
    foreach ($readCalls->classification->{'class'} as $classes) {
        $ClassificationClass[] = implode(" ", array('p' => (string)$classes['p']));
    }
    $responeArray[] = $ClassificationClass;
    $nilaineg = $ClassificationClass[0];
    $nilainet = $ClassificationClass[1];
    $nilaipos = $ClassificationClass[2];
    $_counter++;

    /**
     *  Echo from inside the loop
    **/
    echo $nilaineg . ' ' . $nilainet . ' ' . $nilaipos . '<br />';
}
```

Or alternatively, place them into another array, where you can loop through them later, and this'll keep to the original `return` statement you had included previously.

```
foreach ($xmlResp->readCalls->classify as $readCalls) {
   //Code..
   $ReturnArray[] = $nilaineg . ' ' . $nilainet . ' ' . $nilaipos;
}
return $ReturnArray;
```

Then later on, you can use:

```
print_r( $ReturnedArray );

Array =>
    (
        [0] => 0.999999 5.65423e-007 2.3301e-008
        [1] => 0.333333 0.333333 0.333333
        //etc
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Mackie, i'll try soon